# Spring Data JPA: Named method without JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I would like to have a single-method interface with the method:

```
boolean existsByStrAndStatus(String str, Character status);
```

and have it work as-is as a named method. However, all the examples I've seen of this inherit from `JpaRepository` and I don't want to inherit from this interface as any implementation that I write (for testing purposes) also need to inherit all the built-in convenience methods that `JpaRepository` provide such as `findAll`, `flush` etc.. I am well aware of mocking frameworks, but I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve using for example Mockito.

Is there an alternative to `JpaRepository` where I can still `@Autowire` this repository as I see fit, but if I need to write an implementation I only need to implement my own method?

Comment: So, you want to put custom implementation of repository in you tests and mock (by yourself) only one method?

Comment: @ByeBye that's right, in this particular case.

Comment: Why you cant create you own Mock - `RepositoryImpl implements Repository` then implement your method and leave rest without implementation

Comment: @ByeBye I think `Repository` was what I was looking for. Feel a bit silly now that I read it out loud. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create custom implementation of your interface:

```
class TestRepository implements Repository
```

Which will implement only your custom method and rest leave unimplemented. Then you can use it in your tests.